# Cannot find instance of dynamically added UserControl .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a **UserControl** which I am loading into a div which is inside an **UpdatePanel**. Here is my code for loading it:

```
controls.IDLControl IdlControl = LoadControl(@"~/controls/IDLControl.ascx") as controls.IDLControl;
IdlControl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
IdlControl.ID = "IDLControl";
spGroup.Controls.Clear();
spGroup.Controls.Add(IdlControl);
```

And here is my code for trying to retrieve an instance of it:

```
controls.IDLControl IdlControl = RecursiveFindControl(this, "IDLControl") as controls.IDLControl;

private Control RecursiveFindControl(Control targetControl, string findControlId) {
    if (targetControl.HasControls()) {
        foreach (Control childControl in targetControl.Controls) {
            if (childControl.ID == findControlId) {
                return childControl;
            }

            RecursiveFindControl(childControl, findControlId);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

But, all I get is null. I need help on figuring this out.

AFAIK, I need to re-add the control to the page on pre-init but it is one of the controls that can be added depending on which option is selected from a drop down list (which also is filled dynamically). I am stuck trying to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: You would not get it until you add it back in the `Page_Init` event. You can always check for the Selected option in the drop down list in the `Page_Init` event and decide whether to add your user control or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this to add your control back in the `Page_Init` based on the option selected in your `DropDownList`.

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (drpYourDropDown.Items.Count > 0 && drpYourDropDown.SelectedItem.Text == "yourOption")
        { 
            AddIDLControl();
        }
    }
}

private void AddIDLControl()
{
    controls.IDLControl IdlControl = LoadControl(@"~/controls/IDLControl.ascx") as controls.IDLControl;
    IdlControl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
    IdlControl.ID = "IDLControl";
    spGroup.Controls.Clear();
    spGroup.Controls.Add(IdlControl);
}
```

Comment: I copied the code over (almost) but it is not working. My drop down list is empty in the page_init so I have no way to track what was selected before it went to postback. I tried using a hiddenfield but even that was blanked out on postback. So I moved the code to load up the dropdown into Page_Init and moved the code to re-add the user control into Page_Load and now it works.

Comment: On second look, the data in the user control is now lost during the process if they are not marked as runat="server". This is not a big deal and I can handle it easily. Thanks for your help.